# Rsync include or exclude directories using text file

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm using rsync to backup some data from a remote host.
this is how I'm using the rsync cmd:

```
rsync --dry-run -avhi -e ssh --include-from=/home/rsync_list/test.txt root@10.10.4.61:/ /mnt/BACKUP/my_BACKUP/
```

this is the file /home/rsync_list/test.txt

```
+ /usr/acs/conf/**
+ /usr/acs/bin/**
+ /raid0/opmdps/TEMP_folder/**
- *
```

I want to copy only the listed folders excluding the remaining files.
I always get

```
receiving file list ... done

sent 103 bytes  received 48 bytes  302.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? How should I write the rsync command if I would like to sync, for example, only /raid0/opmdps/TEMP_folder/ without its subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you really only tried with the command you posted?
Not only you are using "--dry-run" option, even the output indicates this:

```
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Please consult the manpage:

```
 -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
```

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

May I suggest you give it a run *without* `--dry-run`?

Comment: I tried the command without the --dry-run but the output is the same